# Keep the selection in a textarea

Tags: javascript, selection, onblur

Can I prevent the loss of selection in the "onblur" event?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang = "en" lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <script type = "text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName ("textarea")[0];

                textarea.onblur = function () {
                    alert ("Should keep selection");

                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>

        <title>Select me!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <textarea>Select me!</textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want you visitors to select a textarea and then disable them for blurring the textarea so they keep selecting the text in the textarea? sounds strange...

Comment: I can think of a good reason somebody might want to do this. Let's say they are doing 'on the fly' validation, as-in: preventing the user from moving on to another field before filling something valid into the textarea (or textbox, or other input). I am currently working on a tool that allows users to populate MANY textareas (its an interactive survey exercise); if there's a duplicate, I'd like to alert to them IMMEDIATELY; as doing-so only 'on submit' makes it a more painful experience. 
People need to remember that there's more to inputs than 'common forms'.

Comment: My use case: pulling up an md-menu with options designed to manipulate the selected text.  It's not super convenient that the selection wants to disappear as soon as the menu comes up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's a good idea. A user with mouse in his/her hand can click anywhere on the page. If you get him/her back into the textarea, it won't be following the principles of [web accessibility](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/accessibility).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you mean you want to remember the selection, even if the user focuses on another element, so that if they go back to the textarea, the same text will still be selected. Is this the case?

If so, I think the easiest thing would be to put the textarea in an iframe in the same domain. Each document maintains its own selection context. Of course, you'll need to read the data from the textarea, and probably copy it to a hidden field in your form, as you can't have fields in a form in another document, so you need to make a sort of proxy.

Answer (score 2):

```
textarea.onblur = function () {
    alert("Should keep selection");
    textarea.focus();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this though. But you never know somebody's reasons.

Comment: What did you change? *Why* did you change it? What is the idea/gist? An explanation would be in order. From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4008240/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

I've prepare this js class for you:

```
class SelectionHolder{
    constructor(element_id){
        this.element = document.getElementById(element_id);
        this.selection_start = null;
        this.selection_end = null;
    }
    setListener(object){
        this.element.onfocus = ()=>{object.reselect();}
        this.element.onblur = ()=>{object.update();}
    }
    update(){
        this.selection_start = this.element.selectionStart;
        this.selection_end = this.element.selectionEnd;
    }
    reselect(){
        this.element.setSelectionRange( this.selsection_start, this.selection_end, "forward");
    }
}
```

Then use it for your elements

```
Let my_holder = SelectionHolder("my-text-area-id");
my_holder.setListener(my_holder)
```