# How to prevent "deselection" of selected text in a textarea when clicking outside of it?

Tags: javascript, highlight

Hi,

I have a normal textarea like this:

```
<textarea id="usermsg"></textarea>
```

I want to be able to select text within it and then click a button somewhere on the page to perform a function with that selection but the text gets deselected as I click outside the text area. Any way to prevent that?

I tried this

```
//clicking the 'test' element will not deselect text.
var test = document.getElementById("usermsg");
test.onmousedown = function(e){
  e = e || window.click;
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

but no use. This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5zg1v2f6/

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008207/keep-the-selection-in-a-textarea

Comment: But, your textarea has no value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep the selection in a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008207/keep-the-selection-in-a-textarea)

Comment: no duplicate and that topic doesnt even answer my question. The chosen answer there only says "its a bad idea" so...